# How to change the vertex style for editing?

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, style, circle

When I use drag feature, then the circles on the polygon edge has the same style. 
For example, [this OpenLayers site](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/modify-feature.html).

I need to change it, I mean they need to be a different color.

What is their (cycles) style attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `vertexRenderIntent` property of `ModifyFeature` control. For example:

```javascript
var vertexStyle = {
    strokeColor: "#ff0000",
    fillColor: "#ff0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 3,
    graphicName: "cross"
}

var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default'],
    "vertex": vertexStyle
}, {extendDefault: false});

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('features', {styleMap: styleMap});
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(layer, {vertexRenderIntent: "vertex"}));
```

At result we have the following style:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The approach outlined by @drnextgis is the correct one to follow. However, be aware that there is currently a bug in OpenLayers (as of version 2.11) that means if you add a unique values renderer to the `StyleMap` using the `addUniqueValueRules` method then the drag handles will disappear.

If you encounter this please look at [my question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29817/openlayers-feature-edit-handles-not-appearing-when-adduniquevaluerules-applied) for details of how to work around it.