# OpenLayers2 ModifyFeature and styling

Tags: openlayers-2, features, style

In OpenLayers, I have a Vector layer with a `StyleMap` and `SelectFeature` and `ModifyFeature` controls, like this:

```
vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('My Vector Layer', {extractAttributes: true,
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':{
                strokeColor: "${customColor}",
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                fillColor: "${customColor}",
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }}) }); 
map.addLayer(vector_layer);


selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vector_layer,
                {onSelect: onFeatureSelect, onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect});
map.addControl(selectControl);
selectControl.activate();
modify_control = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(vector_layer);
map.addControl(modify_control);
```

When I tick a checkbox on the page, the ModifyFeature control is activated:

```
modify_control.activate();
modify_control.mode |= OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.ROTATE;
modify_control.mode |= OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.DRAG;
```

The problem is this: when I remove the `StyleMap`, `ModifyFeature` shows the handles to drag and rotate the feature. *With* the `StyleMap`, they are not visible.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered the same problem I did, [here is the question I asked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29817/openlayers-feature-edit-handles-not-appearing-when-adduniquevaluerules-applied/30460#30460). I'm convinced that this is a bug in OpenLayers and will be opening a bug tracker issue for it. In the meantime I have found a work around and have posted an answer against my original question. Take a look as it should give you what you need.

Comment: Yes, this issue gave me a headache. Thank you very much for your answer!