# change style of newly drawn points

Tags: openlayers-2, features, style

I've a vector layer with a bunch of draw controls on it. You can add polygons, points and you can modify polygon.

Now I changed the style of the points so they have a nice pin-like image. But them I noticed when I select the modify polygon tool and select a polygon, the handles on the polygon are also replaced by my point-image. How do I fix that?

```
this.panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
        allowDepress: true,
        autoActivate: false
    });
    this.controls = {
        "polygon": new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {
            "title": "New Zone"
        }),
        "POI": new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point, {
            "title": "New POI",
            "displayClass": "olControlDrawPoi"
        }),
        "modify": new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(this.layer, {
            "standalone": false,
            "title": "Edit Zone"
        }),
        "clear": new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
            displayClass: "olControlClearLayer",
            trigger: myLocations.clearLayer,
            title: "Clearlayer"
        })
    };
    for (key in this.controls) {
        this.panel.addControls(this.controls[key]);
    }

    myMap.map.addControl(this.panel);
```

I tried adding the style in the Point Handler but that has no effect.
I also tried to set a feature property so I can use a symbolizer in the style, but i can't figure out how to add this property before the feature is actually drawn. (so this works, but only after a layer.redraw().

So I want to have defautl styling for the polygons and its handels when its in modify mode, but I do want a nice marker image for my newly drawn points.

Any ideas?

Comment: d'you have problem with cursor when you on modify control? actually if you share some screenshot it will be very helpful. Good Luck :)

Comment: If you modify a polygon, you select it and you get handles on each corner. These handles get the same style as I set for my points. I don't want that. http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/modify-feature.html If you look at this example. I mean the yellow circles. They change into the same style as i set for points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in this posting:
[How to change the vertex style for editing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28822/how-to-change-the-vertex-style-for-editing)

You have to create separate style and render intent for handles ("vertex" in above example) and set it with vertexRenderIntent option of modify control.